# How to disable periodic DAG parsing in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

We are facing an issue where dynamically-generated DAGs are periodically disappearing from the UI for some time (usually they are gone for a couple of minutes). DAGs keep being scheduled and executed correctly in this period, so it seems like it only affects the UI.

We think this is due to Airflow periodically parsing the DAG files, which in our case takes a long time (we have ~1000 dynamically-generated DAGs from user-provided YAML files).

We currently bake-in all of our definitions into the Docker image, so there isn't really a need to periodically parse the DAG definitions after deployment.

We tried setting the [dag-dir-list-interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-dir-list-interval) and [min-file-process-interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval) parameters to some big value (86400), but that didn't seem to help and DAGs are still periodically missing very frequently.

Is there a way to completely disable periodic DAG parsing? Or are we looking in the wrong direction for this issue?

Comment: does the time between disappearing in the UI changed after you changed the parameters ?

Comment: @ozs no, it didn't change

Comment: @Alexander Did you find any other concrete solution as we're also facing the same issue?

Comment: @VaibS We didn't find any other solution, but the problem went away completely by bumping min-serialized-dag-update-interval like mentioned in the accepted answer. In our case this hack works fine because we bake-in our DAGs into the container, so we don't need periodic serializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we mitigated the issue by bumping the [min-serialized-dag-update-interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.3/configurations-ref.html#min-serialized-dag-update-interval) parameter to some big value like 86400 (from the default of 30).

Comment: Could you please explain how it is different from min-file-process-interval. Also did you change min_serialized_dag_fetch_interval as well?

Comment: @VaibS Looks like DAG serialization is done regardless of dag-dir-list-interval and min-file-process-interval, and only min-serialized-dag-update-interval affects it. And no, we did not change min_serialized_dag_fetch_interval.